# Why Does EventListener for 'load' Work at Bottom of Body, but Not at Top?

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener, q

My load event is supposed to call a function that assigns initial values to the elements of a form.

And I really don't understand why my 'load' EventListener script works at the bottom of the body buy not at the top?

After all, the function isn't called until the page fully loads, so it doesn't seem it should matter.

Note: I put it in the `<body>`, because the `<head>` section is provided by my `<%@ include>` code.  And putting it there didn't work either.

What am I doing wrong?

Here is all the relevant code.  I basically have a single index.HTML page with a frame in which all other pages are opened. This example has the load EventListener script in the body of one of those secondary pages.

**index.HTML**

```
<html>
  <head >
    ...LOADS ALL JS SCRIPTS    
  </head>
  <body id="body-outer-index" >
    <iframe id="iframe-outer-index" src="jsp-pages/level-1/pages/index.jsp">
    </iframe>
  </body>
</html>
```

**index.jsp**

```
<%@ include file='/jsp-pages/level-1/headers/beg.jsp'%>
  ... This include declares a var ('SH') that stores
  ... a reference to the index.HTML that has all the 
  ... JS Script Files
  ... Then is adds  
  |**<html>******************************************|
  |**    <head>                                    **|
  |**        ...                                   **|
  |**    </head>                                   **|
  |**    <body>                                    **|
  |*******<div class='content-block' style="100vh">**|

  |******* then index.jsp code begins ***************|
  |         <div>                                    |
  |           a 3-column css table used as the       | 
  |           header for all pages                   |
  |         </div>                                   |
  |                                                  |
  |    <script>  **FAILS** to call the function      |
  |      window.addEventListener('load', SH.fillForm("form1"), false);
  |    </script>                                     |
  |                                                  |    
  |         <form>                                   |
  |           <input>...                             |
  |           <select>...                            |
  |           ...                                    |
  |           <submit>...                            |
  |         </form>                                  |
  |                                                  |
  |    <script>  SUCCESSFULLY calls the function      !
  |      window.addEventListener('load', SH.fillForm("form1"), false);
  |    </script>                                     |
  |                                                  |
  |*******</div>*************************************|
      </body>
    <html>
```

This is the additional code requested (And it works when called).

```
function fillForm (formNo) {
  if (formNo === "form1") {
    var formElements = getFormElements(formNo);  
    var len = Object.keys(formElements).length;
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
      if(formElements[i].id === "selectmiddlesep" ) {
        formElements[i].value = "*space*";
      } else if (formElements[i].id === "selectlastsep" ) {
        formElements[i].value = "*space*";
      } else if (formElements[i].id === "1stmiddletype" ) {
          formElements[i].value = "*initial*";
      } else if (formElements[i].id === "2ndmiddletype" ) {
          formElements[i].value = "*none*";
      } else {
        formElements[i].value = formElements[i].id;
      }
    }
  } else {
    /*
     * there may be other pages for other forms someday, but not today.
     * so if this function is called with a select element that is not in 
     * form1 there is a serious code error
     */
    alert ("fillForm is not form1");
  }
}
```

Comment: Please post the code of the `SH.fillForm("form1")` function. Does it even return an event handler function? Does it try to access the element with that name?

Comment: Posted.  But I don't understand. SH.fillForm () is called by the EventListener when a 'load' event is thrown by the browser after the page is loaded. Isn't it?  My function doesn't return anything. It just responds when called.  And it get's called when I code the EventListner in <script> I put at the bottom of the <body> element.  Not called when the exact same <script> is put at the top of the <body> element.  I mean it works now.  I just don't like it at the bottom of the <body> element.  [Sorry for my delay. But I just realized I'm not getting emails when there's a response.]

Comment: "*SH.fillForm () is called by the EventListener when a 'load' event is thrown*" - no, you are calling the function immediately, and pass its result to `addEventListener`. You need to pass a function that calls `fillForm`, i.e. `window.addEventListener('load', function(e) { SH.fillForm("form1"); }, false);`. Only then the function will be called when the load event happens, and then it will also find the element.

Comment: Got it.  I need to put my function inside the function that is run by the event listener. That works for all my other problems as well, e.g. adding a listener to the form element that catches all the change events.  My function needs to be called by the function I declare in the addEventListner .... formElement.addEventListener('change", function () {my function();}, false); Thank you. I can't figure out how to mark this as the Correct Answer?